# Tasks API and OAuth 2.0 on Android sample

Tags: android, api, google-api, task

i'm very new to android devolopment
i tried to run the sample project given in this example 
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples

but when i run it, it gives a force close error. after a messing around i figure that it has only list activity not activity class as others. why? how to fix it?
. my idea is to create a android software which i can push tasks from the server to the app then the app will add those as tasks in the phone? any sample apps like that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to set the permission for Oauth?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

New Task sample required Google Play Service Library to run you need to set up it and added into build path of your application.